# Column Issue in React and Material UI

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have three columns and I wanted to add a column for removing each row.
I need to add a column for "removing" on the right. Is it possible?
How will I do it?

**CODESANDBOX:**  [CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/three-rows-table-using-material-ui-and-react-forked-0chj7l?file=/CustomTableRow.js)

```
const CustomTableRow = ({ row, index, arrayHelpers }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <TableRow
        sx={{
          "th, td": { border: 0 }
        }}
      >
        <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
          <FastField
            name={`rows.${index}.attribute`}
            component={TextField}
            fullWidth
          />
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell>
          <FastField
            name={`rows.${index}.ruleId`}
            component={TextField}
            fullWidth
          />
        </TableCell>
      </TableRow>
      <TableRow>
        <TableCell colSpan={2}>
          <FastField
            name={`rows.${index}.thirdRow`}
            component={TextField}
            fullWidth
          />
        </TableCell>
      </TableRow>
      {/* <TableCell align="right">
        <IconButton
          aria-label="delete"
          onClick={() => arrayHelpers.remove(index)}
          size="small"
        >
          <RemoveCircleOutlineIcon sx={{ fontSize: "1.25rem" }} />
        </IconButton>
      </TableCell> */}
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a rough start, but edit the rows to occupy 5 columns of space, 4 for the row data/fields and 1 for the remove button. You can tweak the column spans to adjust the UI to your liking.

Table

```
<Table sx={{ minWidth: 650 }} aria-label="simple table">
  <TableHead>
    <TableRow
      sx={{
        th: { border: 0 }
      }}
    >
      <TableCell colSpan={2}>Attribute</TableCell>
      <TableCell colSpan={2}>Rule ID</TableCell>
      <TableCell />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
      <TableCell colSpan={4}>Third Row</TableCell>
      <TableCell />
    </TableRow>
  </TableHead>
  <TableBody>
    {values.rows?.map((row, index) => (
      <CustomTableRow
        key={row.id}
        row={row}
        index={index}
        arrayHelpers={arrayHelpers}
      />
    ))}
  </TableBody>
</Table>
```

CustomTableRow

```
const CustomTableRow = ({ row, index, arrayHelpers }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <TableRow
        sx={{
          "th, td": { border: 0 }
        }}
      >
        <TableCell colSpan={2} component="th" scope="row">
          <FastField
            name={`rows.${index}.attribute`}
            component={TextField}
            fullWidth
          />
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell colSpan={2}>
          <FastField
            name={`rows.${index}.ruleId`}
            component={TextField}
            fullWidth
          />
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell align="center" colSpan={1} rowSpan={2}>
          <IconButton
            aria-label="delete"
            onClick={() => arrayHelpers.remove(index)}
            size="small"
          >
            <RemoveCircleOutlineIcon sx={{ fontSize: "1.25rem" }} />
          </IconButton>
        </TableCell>
      </TableRow>
      <TableRow
        sx={{
          "th, td": { border: 0 }
        }}
      >
        <TableCell colSpan={4}>
          <FastField
            name={`rows.${index}.thirdRow`}
            component={TextField}
            fullWidth
          />
        </TableCell>
      </TableRow>
    </>
  );
};
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Drew. Can we still put a divider or horizontal line after each row? So we can distinguish or separate them?

Comment: @Joseph It's a bit difficult trying to shoehorn two rows into a single table row ***and*** get the single row styling working well. My suggestion here would be to use a Grid for part of the row layout. https://codesandbox.io/s/column-issue-in-react-and-material-ui-nk6cw7?file=/CustomTableRow.js

Answer (score -1):

I think Column issue is solved and it might be helpful to you as well
Please check the file which have been updated below :

**demo.js**

```
    import React from "react";
    import Table from "@mui/material/Table";
    import TableBody from "@mui/material/TableBody";
    import TableCell from "@mui/material/TableCell";
    import TableContainer from "@mui/material/TableContainer";
    import TableHead from "@mui/material/TableHead";
    import TableRow from "@mui/material/TableRow";
    import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";
    import { Box, Button } from "@mui/material";
    import AddIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Add";
    import { FieldArray, Form, Formik } from "formik";
    import CustomTableRow from "./CustomTableRow";
    
    const CustomTable = () => {
      const handleSubmit = () => {};
    
      return (
        <TableContainer component={Paper}>
          <Formik
            initialValues={[
              {
                id: 1,
                attribute: "",
                ruleId: "",
                thirdRow: ""
              }
            ]}
            onSubmit={handleSubmit}
          >
            {({ values }) => (
              <Form>
                <FieldArray
                  name="rows"
                  render={(arrayHelpers) => (
                    <React.Fragment>
                      <Box>
                        <Button
                          variant="contained"
                          type="submit"
                          startIcon={<AddIcon />}
                          onClick={() =>
                            arrayHelpers.unshift({
                              id: Date.now(),
                              attribute: "",
                              ruleId: "",
                              thirdRow: ""
                            })
                          }
                        >
                          Add New
                        </Button>
                      </Box>
                      <Table sx={{ minWidth: 650 }} aria-label="simple table">
                        <TableHead>
                          <TableRow
                            sx={{
                              th: { border: 0 }
                            }}
                          >
                            <TableCell>Attribute</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>Rule ID</TableCell>
                            <TableCell colSpan={2}>Actions</TableCell>
                          </TableRow>
                        </TableHead>
                        <TableBody>
                          {values.rows?.map((row, index) => (
                            <CustomTableRow
                              key={row.id}
                              row={row}
                              index={index}
                              arrayHelpers={arrayHelpers}
                            />
                          ))}
                        </TableBody>
                      </Table>
                    </React.Fragment>
                  )}
                />
              </Form>
            )}
          </Formik>
        </TableContainer>
      );
    };
    
    export default CustomTable;
```

**CustomTableRow.js**

```
    import { TableCell, TableRow, TextField, IconButton } from "@mui/material";
    import { FastField } from "formik";
    import RemoveCircleOutlineIcon from "@mui/icons-material/RemoveCircleOutline";
    import { Button } from "@mui/material";
    const CustomTableRow = ({ row, index, arrayHelpers }) => {
      return (
        <>
          <TableRow
            sx={{
              "th, td": { border: 0 }
            }}
          >
            <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
              <FastField
                name={`rows.${index}.attribute`}
                component={TextField}
                fullWidth
              />
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell>
              <FastField
                name={`rows.${index}.ruleId`}
                component={TextField}
                fullWidth
              />
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell>
              <FastField
                name={`rows.${index}.ruleId`}
                component={TextField}
                fullWidth
              />
            </TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </>
      );
    };
    
    CustomTableRow.displayName = "CustomTableRow";
    
    export default CustomTableRow;
```

Comment: The third TextField should be there too. It must not be removed

Comment: @Joseph I added the TextField in the code. Please update it according to your need. I think column issue might be solved it was the main question right ?

Comment: This is wrong. Placement of TextField should be the same as before. Its just add there is an addition of a new column for remove

Answer (score -3):

Look over your imports: Verify that the appropriate Material UI components have been loaded. You should integrate the Grid component for columns.

Verify your code: Verify that the Props and Syntax for the Grid component are accurate. Make sure that the xs, sm, md, lg, and xl props add up to 12. The Grid component utilises a 12-column layout.

```
import { Grid } from '@material-ui/core';
    
    function App() {
      return (
        <Grid container spacing={2}>
          <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
            {/* Left column content */}
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
            {/* Right column content */}
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      );
    }
```

Make sure there are no CSS styles that clash with the Material UI designs by checking for conflicts. The And'so make use the total cost effective date and'so make use the total cost-effective date and so make use the total cost effective date and'so make use the total cost effective date and'so make use the